# Implemented `operator<` still gives error - no match for 'operator <' (opereate types are const StorageFile' and 'const StorageFile')

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, qmap

I have a custom struct named `StorageFile` which contains some information about a file do be stored in a database.

```
class StorageFile : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT

  public:
     int ID = -1;
     QString filename;
     QString relativeLocation;
     MediaType type;
     QDateTime dateLastChanged;
     quint64 size;
     QString sha256;
     //...

     explicit StorageFile(QObject* parent = nullptr);
     StorageFile(const StorageFile& other);
     StorageFile& operator= (const StorageFile& other);
     bool operator< (const StorageFile& storageFile);      < --------- implemented operator
     bool operator== (const StorageFile& storageFile);

     //...
}
```

I am adding these StorageFile objects to a [QMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html), and the `QMap` **requires** the [operator<](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#details) to be implemented - which I have. The compiler gives the following error:

```
F:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_32\include\QtCore/qmap.h:71:17: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const StorageFile' and 'const StorageFile')
     return key1 < key2;
            ~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Even though I have implemented the required operator, why does it still give this error?

---

**Update**

Adding the definition for the operator:

StorageFile.cpp

```
//...
bool StorageFile::operator <(const StorageFile& storageFile)
{
     return size > storageFile.size;
}
//...
```

After modifying the offending line to:

```
bool operator< (const StorageFile& storageFile) const;
```

An it complained with:

```
path\to\project\libs\storagefile.h:33: error: candidate is: bool StorageFile::operator<(const StorageFile&) const
      bool operator< (const StorageFile& storageFile) const;
           ^~~~~~~~
```

**Solution**

as @cijien mentioned, make sure the operator< has the const keyword & the definition is updated accordingly:

The **StorageFile.h**

```
 bool operator< (const StorageFile& storageFile) const;
```

and **StorageFile.cpp**

```
bool StorageFile::operator<(const StorageFile& storageFile) const
{
     return size > storageFile.size;
}
```

*(note the const keywords at the end of both)*

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem. My bet is on a broken include tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `operator<` is incorrect. To allow `<` to work when the left hand side operand is a `const` object, you need to const-qualify the member `operator<` as well:

```
bool operator< (const StorageFile& storageFile) const;
                                            //  ^^^^^
```

Note that a `map` would usually require that const keys can be compared with `<`, which is what the error message is suggesting.

This is generally how `operator<` should be implemented as a member. You can also write a non-member `operator<` if that works for your use case.

Edit: Looking at your code, it is unclear whether you have *defined* `operator<` at all. Obviously, you need to do that, but it still must be const-qualified.

Comment: thanks very much, I did infact at a definition for my code, thought adding it was not necessary. Making the change as you suggested did infact solve my problem. edit: it has raised another problem

Comment: Depending on the problem, it should probably be a new question.

Comment: Ok, that's good :) If this answer answers the question, go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @cijien simple problem - easily forgetten (question updated with solution) - add this to your answer if you wish